# Change the name of a div Jquery or CSS

Tags: jquery, css

i have this div in my DOM

```
<div class="span4 minus65" id="divChange">
```

I have given it an id so that i can select it with jquery hopefully

What i want to do is change the div to

```
<div class="span12" id="changeBack">
```

when the screen size gets below 600px for example (I have set the id=changeback as im guessing ill need to revert it back?) Im learning jquery so would appreciate some pointers on what to do here to make this happen or is there a way to use CSS media queries? (None than i can think of though)

Any help appreciated

Comment: What makes you think you can't do it with media queries? It's possible if all you need is to change css styles...

Comment: Why do you need to change the `id` of the div? The only deciding factor for the class name change is the size of the window.

Comment: would be really interested in knowing how to use css media queries to achieve this

Comment: I suggest you to look the responsive chapter of bootstrap (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive)

Comment: im using id as i use span4 minus65 class in multiple places and i dont want all of them to change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work. You should take a look at CSS 3 Media Queries as they might help you in accomplishing your task without involving JavaScript.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if($(window).width() < 600 && $("#changeBack").length == 0){
        $("#divChange").attr("id", "changeBack");
    }
    else{
        $("#changeBack").attr("id", "divChange");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `resize` event to detect when the window is resized, and apply the appropriate id accordingly.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if($(this).outerWidth() < 600){
        $('#divChange').attr('id',"changeBack");
    }else{
        $('#changeBack').attr('id',"divChange");
    }
});
```

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/JkypX/

(Resize the results pane in the bottom right corner to see the change occur)

An equivalent effect can be achieved for CSS purposes by maintaining the current ID and using a media query to specify a different style:

```
#divChange{
    color:red;
}
@media all and (max-width: 600px){
    #divChange{
        color:green;
    }
}
```

Whether this suits you more depends, of course, on what you are trying to achieve.

Here is a demonstration of this approach: http://jsfiddle.net/JkypX/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to change the 'id' attribute like so:

```
$('#divChange').attr('id','changeBack');
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the use of media queries. Removing any dependency on jQuery.

http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries

Comment: I understand media queries but am unsure of how to use to change the name of a div